# c# -How to put items from a List<string> to List<object>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put all the items from a list of type string into a list of type object.

Here is my class :

```
public class Object
{
    public string url;
    public bool case;
    public void Add(string item)
    {
        url = item;
    }
}
```

I have tried the following (something is the list of type string from which i'm trying to add elements to my new list of type object) :

```
List<Object> finals = something.OfType<Object>().ToList();
```

and

```
List<Object> finals = new List<Object>(); 
foreach(var item in something)
{
    finals.Add(item);
}
```

What I want is to have "url" from my object class to be equal with each element from the List and "case" to be set as false for all of them.

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance !

Comment: `Object` is a very poor name, you are going to run in to conflicts with `System.Object` very frequently. I would recommend choosing a different name.

Comment: @ScottChamberlan that name was used only for examplification purposes

Comment: @Garnyatar if you want a name for an example class "MyClass" would be better. Creating a List<object> of a List<string> is different from creating a List<MyClass>. In the first case a simple cast of the containing objects would suffice, in the latter new MyClass objects have to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create an instance of `Object`, then you can add it to your list.
The property `case` is false by default.

```
List<Object> finals = new List<Object>(); 
foreach(var item in something)
{
    var newObject = new Object(item);
    finals.Add(newObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can achieve this easily with a one-liner by using LINQ.

```
List<Object> finals = something.Select(s => new Object(s)).ToList();
```

The default value of `bool` is `false`, so you don't need any specific setter for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code that's specific to your case:

```
IEnumerable<Object> finals = strings.Select(s => new Object() { url = s });
```

The `case` property will default to false so you don't have to type it out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Take each item in the list of strings, loop through them and return a list of objects with two properties, url and case. Set case to false. [Yield return](http://www.dotnetperls.com/yield) will return an enumerable interface of objects.

```
public class MyObject {
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool case { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<MyObject> process(List<string> listOfUrls) {
    foreach(var item in listofUrls) {
        yield return new MyObject {
            url = item;
            case = false;
        }
    }
}
```